# Why are two classes needed to create one object

Tags: java, class, object

I am new to java, when i studying this one http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html, I have one doubt raised. that is.

If we want create object need to create two classes or need to create one class?

Because in this application, had created `class Bicycle` and `class BicycleDemo` .

Can anyone guide me for this trivial question?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code;

```
class Bicycle {

    int cadence = 0;
    int speed = 0;
    int gear = 1;

    void changeCadence(int newValue) {
         cadence = newValue;
    }

    void changeGear(int newValue) {
         gear = newValue;
    }

    void speedUp(int increment) {
         speed = speed + increment;   
    }

    void applyBrakes(int decrement) {
         speed = speed - decrement;
    }

    void printStates() {
         System.out.println("cadence:" +
             cadence + " speed:" + 
             speed + " gear:" + gear);
    }
}
```

class BicyleDemo:

```
class BicycleDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create two different 
        // Bicycle objects
        Bicycle bike1 = new Bicycle();
        Bicycle bike2 = new Bicycle();

        // Invoke methods on 
        // those objects
        bike1.changeCadence(50);
        bike1.speedUp(10);
        bike1.changeGear(2);
        bike1.printStates();

        bike2.changeCadence(50);
        bike2.speedUp(10);
        bike2.changeGear(2);
        bike2.changeCadence(40);
        bike2.speedUp(10);
        bike2.changeGear(3);
        bike2.printStates();
    }
}
```

Comment: In your example, you only need *ONE* class: just add your "static void main()" to Bicycle.java and delete BicycleDemo.java.  It's also worth noting that *ANY* class can have it's own "main()".  You select *which* main when you launch Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BicycleDemo` only exists to test `Bicycle` class. You never create an instance (i.e. an object) of `BicycleDemo` class.

Therefore, you don't really need `BicycleDemo`. You can move the main method from `BicycleDemo` to `Bicycle`.

Comment: thanks @eran: so that object created for only class Bicycle right? so may i know, how to run this application with only one class?

Comment: as it was mentioned just move public static void main(String[] args) {...

into Bicycle class

Comment: @selva after moving the main method to Bicycle class, you would use `java Bicycle` instead of `java BicycleDemo` to execute the main method of `Bucycle` class.

Comment: @eran: why they are mentioned one more class, what is that use?

Comment: @selva Sometimes it's useful to separate the "real" code (Bicycle class in this case) from the code that tests the "real" code, which is (BicycleDemo). But since both classes here are for learning purposes, I see no real reason to split them.

Comment: @eran: here is the image, http://imgur.com/giH2LYM tried this code, but shows lots of errors, when i run.

Comment: @selva You copied the main method incorrectly. Notice that you have two `public static void main...` lines in your class, and the first one looks like a mistake.

Comment: @eran: thanks, and i learned 4 types of java applications that is, I am new to java,so which application is better for me to learn? which is better for future use among all the 4 types, thanks.please you have to help me to learn java.

Answer (score 0):

Class is like a shape for instance. Which you have to inicialized via new. BicycleDemo is simply main method holder where you inicialize Bicycle. You can simply move main to Bicycle class but its not recommended way.(main method is entrance point to your application)

```
class Bicycle {

    int cadence = 0;
    int speed = 0;
    int gear = 1;

    void changeCadence(int newValue) {
         cadence = newValue;
    }

    void changeGear(int newValue) {
         gear = newValue;
    }

    void speedUp(int increment) {
         speed = speed + increment;   
    }

    void applyBrakes(int decrement) {
         speed = speed - decrement;
    }

    void printStates() {
         System.out.println("cadence:" +
             cadence + " speed:" + 
             speed + " gear:" + gear);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create two different 
        // Bicycle objects
        Bicycle bike1 = new Bicycle();
        Bicycle bike2 = new Bicycle();

        // Invoke methods on 
        // those objects
        bike1.changeCadence(50);
        bike1.speedUp(10);
        bike1.changeGear(2);
        bike1.printStates();

        bike2.changeCadence(50);
        bike2.speedUp(10);
        bike2.changeGear(2);
        bike2.changeCadence(40);
        bike2.speedUp(10);
        bike2.changeGear(3);
        bike2.printStates();
    }
}
```

Comment: but, when run this , i have lots of errors occured @milkmaid

Comment: @selva I tryed it and it works fine. Post your errors so I can take a look or start new project from scratch and just copy&paste this class. Getting this outpu cadence:50 speed:10 gear:2
cadence:40 speed:20 gear:3

Comment: 3rd line you got there "public static void main(String[] args) {" delete it. or just make full copy&paste

Comment: yes, i got it.. thanks @milkmaid, and i learned 4 types of java applications that is, I am new to java,so which application is better for me to learn? which is better for future use among all the 4 types, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

We can create Object use one or two classes,it is depends on what you like. In spring framework ,class is created by other class, if you  use the design pattern of singleton,you can only use one class.

Comment: User makes no inquiry into spring. Nor does this answer really answer the question. He's asking why he needs two separate classes, one to act as the model and the "demo" which demonstrates how to instantiate and use the class.